# A module providing promisify (denodeify) for AngularJS $q

Tags: angularjs, promise

I would like to share code between my Node.js server and my AngularJS client using browserify. I want to keep the API callback-based on the Node.js side, but use $q promises in the AngularJS code.

Example:

```
// This is the function I am going to share
// It lives in the file 'foo.js'
function foo(cb) {
  // do some async work
  cb(null, result);
}
module.exports = foo;


// In the AngularJS setup, I want to register
// a promisified version of this function
// as an Angular service
app.service('foo', $q.promisify(require('foo.js')));


// My controllers see the usual AngularJS API
app.controller('FooCtrl', ['foo', function(foo) {
  foo().then(function(result) {
    $scope.data = result;
  });
}]);
```

"Full" promise libraries like Q or Bluebird provide tools for converting callback-based functions to promise-returning ones - Q has `denodeify`, Bluebird has `promisify` and `promisifyAll`.

Is there any AngularJS module providing `$q.promisify` or similar?

**NOTE**

I know it's not that difficult to write `promisify` myself, the naive version is only about 16 lines of code. An optimised version can be based on Bluebird's implementation in [promisify.js](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/promisify.js).

The reason why I am asking this question is to avoid reinventing the wheel, so that I can invest my time into things adding more value.

Comment: Literally nothing on client side used node style callbacks ever so I doubt there is $q.promisify

Comment: Related https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6697

Comment: Why don't you use promises on the server side?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `bluebird` or `rsvp` which have a `promisify` method for *thunks* (a *thunk* being any callback in the "node" style of `function(err, arg1, arg2, ...)`).

However, you'd need to have a wrapper that also calls `$scope.$apply()` when the promise is fulfilled.